# how do I update sqlite table with consecutive image filenames

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to update 200 records in a table.  The column is picname with the name of image1.jpg ... to ... image200.jpg.

I just need some general advice on how this is done.

I tried putting it thru a loop, and individually updating each record.

I'm using basic4android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE _table SET picname=(SELECT 'image'||COUNT()||'.jpg' FROM _table AS _ WHERE ROWID<=_table.ROWID)
```